# jQueryMobile default font-size too big, can I downsize for Computer-screen?

Tags: jquery-mobile, responsive-design, font-size

@Phill Pafford gave the solution for my oposite problem: [jquery mobile default font size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6752977/jquery-mobile-default-font-size) using the meta viewport solution. But, this is great for up-sizing the viewport to adapt to a phone screen.

I'm implementing jQM framework only to give a mobile look-n-fell on a "regular" Web-based App that runs on computer screens. And the font looks very big on them! How can I globally down-size the font-size or adapt it (responsive design) to be more appealing (i.e. smaller) on a computer screen?

Thanks!

Comment: you could use a decimal as well, <meta name="viewport" 
      content="width=device-width,initial-scale=0.5,maximum-scale=0.5" />

Comment: Hi Phill, sorry for the delay on my answer. This was the first thing we tried after I read your original post, but it didn't work. Then we tried it again after reading the above comment, but... it's not working. I don't know if the reason of this may be that the App is executing within a jQueryUI dialog and inside the jQueryUI popup I have an iFrame and inside of this iFrame we finally have the jQueryMobile App. Huh? => Webpage(jQueryUI.dialog(iFrame(myApp)))... Any guess?

Comment: Oh and one more thing, I'm trying this on both Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome for desktop (as the app is supposed to run on desktop browsers).

I also tried to do a HelloWorld App:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>HelloWorld</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=0.5,maximum-scale=0.5" />
  <!-- link, and scripts for jqueryMobile 1.2.0 (alpha) here-->
 </head>
 <body>
  <div data-role="page">
   <div data-role="header">
    <h1>My Title</h1>
   </div>
   <div data-role="content"> 
    <p>Hello world</p>  
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your custom stylesheet, not the JQM stylesheet, group your styles with media queries:

```
/* Large desktop */
@media (min-width: 1200px) { font-size: 12px; }

/* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) { ... }

/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 767px) { ... }

/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 480px) { ... }
```

Comment: Hi Weingage! Thanks for your reply, we tried this both in an external custom style sheet and with a <style> section on the <head> of the main file... still nothing. I even did it on a HelloWorld app. Using jQueryMobile 1.2.0 (alpha), can this be it?

Comment: Thank you! (Sorry, I took a while to see you answer, but better late than never)